# centering thumbnails with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

i'm trying to center a group of fluid thumbnails, but they always align left instead of center.

here's the jsfiddle that shows the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/4040newb/bVa2Z/3/

**you may have to enlarge the output window to see the thumbnails side by side and observe the problem**

```
 <div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row-fluid">

        <ul class="thumbnails">

    <li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>


</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: means you just copy-paste it? Are you aware that you need to call twitterbootstrap framework in the resources?

Comment: yea, i didn't include calling the framework, because that's assumed. this is just the body of the html.

Comment: and obviously i tried copying and pasting, and that didn't work. my question is what i should add to this code to get it right.

Comment: are you loading any other CSS files that could be conflicting?

Comment: okay so i got jsfiddle working, this illustrates my problem centering thumbnails

Comment: the question is how to get it so the group of thumbnails stays centered on the page. you may have to open up to window for the thumbnails to go side by side.